# redirect page a in domain x to page b in domain y

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I know it may be duplicate in some cases but I couldn't find an exact answer for this.
I've changed my website url and I created all pages in new format, now I want to redirect old urls to new one, the urls are in persian format so this my old domain address:
old: https://sisnogroup.com/%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B5%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B4-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%86

new: https://sisnogroup.ge/fa/%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86
I want to redirect it permenantly to new one.

I did some code in webconfig/iisrewrite but it returns 404.
what is the exact web.config code to do this?

```
                <rule name="Redirect to domain 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B5%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B4-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%86$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://sisnogroup.ge/fa/%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```

**Update**

this is the log from failed request tracing:

```
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>10</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x400</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-06-23T08:45:41.197Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80009014-0000-9500-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="16364" ThreadID="13304"/>
  <Computer>WIN-KF45KMECN9L</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80009014-0000-9500-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Pattern">^%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B5%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B4-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%86$</Data>
  <Data Name="Input">robots.txt</Data>
  <Data Name="Negate">false</Data>
  <Data Name="Matched">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>PATTERN_MATCH</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Rewrite</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{0469ABFA-1BB2-466A-B645-E3E15A02F38B}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @samwu I did the same, I can't find any reasonable information in logs.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was about Persian characters in URLs,
in the pattern section of the rule, I copied and past the Persian encoded character so it seems it's different from the exact value of the URL,
for example, in the pattern section, you should use something like:

```
^بهترین-شرکت-خدمات-در-ایران&
```

not something like that I mentioned in my question which contains % signs.
hope it helps other with the same problem.